# Query that pulls results from tables A and B, then uses results to get rows from table A

Tags: php, mysql

Someone gave me the query below from a previous question I asked on Stack Overflow.  It's supposed to pull "submissionid" from two tables, called **submission** and **addresses**,  where `zip = '$zip'`.  (Both "submissionid" and "zip" appear in the two tables.)

Then, I would like to look up the field "title" corresponded to all of these "submissionid"s.  The field "title only appears in the table **submission**.

Then, I would like the query to generate a list of all of the resulting "title"s.

How could I modify the query to do this?  The query below seems to omit results from **submission**.

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.title, s.points, s.submissionid
         FROM submission s 
         INNER JOIN addresses ad
         on ad.submissionid = s.submissionid
         WHERE ad.zip = '$zip'
     ORDER BY s.points DESC, s.title ASC";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*the query below seems to omit results from submission*"?  Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: @eggyal if a row is in the table **submission**, and it has `zip = '$zip'`, the query does not return it.  I want it to.  It does return the correct results for rows in the table **addresses**.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `OR s.zip = '$zip'` to your `WHERE` clause.  With a little additional tidying, your query becomes:

```sql
SELECT   submission.title, submission.points, submission.submissionid
FROM     submission JOIN addresses USING (submissionid)
WHERE    submission.zip = '$zip' OR addresses.zip = '$zip'
ORDER BY submission.points DESC, submission.title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want.

Putting your original query into subquery, and select all submissions with same submission id

```
SELECT
  title,
  points,
  submissionid
FROM submission
WHERE submissionid IN (
  # Original Query
  SELECT s.submissionid
  FROM submission s
    JOIN addresses ad ON ad.submissionid = s.submissionid
  WHERE ad.zip = '$zip'
)
ORDER BY 
  points DESC, 
  title ASC
```